# Errors with Code Coverage in VS2012 unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am adding unit tests to an existing solution for the first time.  This is a legacy solution with a variety of project types.  My unit test project references only one other project in the solution which is a class library.

My tests run fine, but when I select “Analyze Code Coverage for Selected Tests”, Visual Studio either crashes or I get the following error in the Output – Tests window:

No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))
No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

I tried running unit tests and code coverage in a separate new solution and it all works fine.  This makes me believe it is a problem with the existing code and/or solution.

I don’t even know where to start looking.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Skip

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit.  One of the projects in my solution is a Red Gate SQL Connect project.  When I unload the project from my solution code coverage seems to work fine.

Comment: (I work for Red Gate.)  Thanks for your report. We've tracked down the issue to a bug in the Microsoft open source library mpfproj10.codeplex.com that SQL Connect uses. We've fixed the source in the copy we are using and a fix has now been uploaded to the Visual Studio Gallery.